# How can I run a VBS script with arguments inside C++ program?

Tags: c++, vbscript

I want to do something like that:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string input = string(argv[1]);

    // some code to run MyScript.vbs with arg=input

    return 0;
    }
```

What should I write in the third line of that code to run the script with arg from my program input?

Comment: [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function? Possibly not the best option, but probably easiest to implement...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc <= 1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::string parameters;

    for (std::size_t i{ 1 }; i < argc; ++i)
        parameters += argv[i];

    CreateProcessA("wscript.exe", const_cast<LPSTR>( parameters.c_str() ), nullptr,
        nullptr, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

but that's somewhat pointless. Just call `wscript.exe` directly.

Comment: With that code I get the problem: _It is not allowed to use usual pointers to reference classes or C ++ / CLI interface classes_

Comment: Then you are not writing in C++.

Comment: @kosmo_tony C (style) variant: Allocate a large enough char array (possibly of size 1024: `char buffer[1024];`) and concatenate the arguments into this one. Make sure that you don't exceed array bounds, though (use [`strncat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat), not `strcat`)!

Comment: @Aconcagua The question is tagged C++ and vbscript which implies Windows so chances of not being able to use a full implementation of Standard C++ and the Windows API is negligible.

Comment: @Aconcagua the error message kosmo_tony got ("It is not allowed to use usual pointers to reference classes or C ++ / CLI interface classes") disqualifies for C++.

Comment: @Swordfish "error"? Didn't interprete the sentence as such, but as being a citation from the task... OK, let's forget about then...